# Pandas: Biggest index smaller then a date

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, indexing, dataframe

Given the following exemplary Pandas `DataFrame` `x`:

```
             a    b
2014-08-07   0.1  2.0
2014-08-18   0.2  4.0
2014-12-16   0.3  0.0
2015-01-16   0.4  2.3
2015-02-16   0.5  2.1
2015-03-18   0.6  7.0
```

The indices are of the type `datetime.date`.

I want to write a function that takes a parameter `start` of the type `datetime.datetime` such that it gives me the biggest index which is smaller then `start`.

For example, for `start = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 20, 17, 30)` the biggest index that is smaller then `start` is, is `2015-01-16`.

This would give me the most recent change in `a` and `b` namely `x.loc[dt(2015,1,16)]`.

Comment: for some reason `np.searchsorted` doesn't work but this does: `df.index[df.index < start][-1]`

Comment: if you can sort the items, by time, you can use binary search/bisection to find this in log(n) time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pandas asof function is meant for this:

```
x.index.asof(start)
```

It can be used on series or on datetime indexes.

See:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.asof.html

Answer (score 1):

Testing solutions:

```
Out[4]: 
              a    b
2014-08-07  0.1  2.0
2014-08-18  0.2  4.0
2014-12-16  0.3  0.0
2015-01-16  0.4  2.3
2015-02-16  0.5  2.1
2015-03-18  0.6  7.0

In [5]: %timeit df[df.index < pd.to_datetime("2015-09-01")].ix[-1, :]
The slowest run took 5.15 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 620 µs per loop

In [6]: %timeit df.iloc[:df.index.values.searchsorted(np.datetime64("2015-09-01"))].ix[-1, :]
The slowest run took 5.53 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 293 µs per loop

In [7]: %timeit df[:pd.to_datetime("2015-09-01")].ix[-1, :]
The slowest run took 5.66 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1000 loops, best of 3: 450 µs per loop

__main__:6: FutureWarning: TimeSeries is deprecated. Please use Series
In [10]: %timeit alecsolution(df)
1000 loops, best of 3: 503 µs per loop
```

I think the fastest is:

```
df.iloc[:df.index.values.searchsorted(np.datetime64("2015-09-01"))].ix[-1, :]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using TimeSeries but for DataFrame is the same.

Basically it iterates over df, for each iteration checks if the date is bigger than 'start', if not saves the date just checked as 'previous', if yes then 'previous' is your result.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.TimeSeries({'2014-08-07': ['0.1', '2.0'],
                    '2014-08-18': ['0.2', '4.0'],
                    '2014-12-16': ['0.3', '0.0'],
                    '2015-01-16': ['0.4', '2.3'],
                    '2015-02-16': ['0.5', '2.1'],
                    '2015-03-18': ['0.6', '7.0']})

start = datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 20, 17, 30)
result = False
previous_i = False

for i,row in df.iteritems():
    if pd.to_datetime(i) >= start:
        result = previous_i
        break # you don't need to check further
    else:
        previous_i = i

print(result)


>>> 2015-01-16
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x[:start.date()].ix[-1, :]
```

provides a Pandas `Series` with the entries in the of the desired index.